# What is the point of the second route lookup after OUTPUT?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, port-forwarding

According to the [packet path diagram](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg), and its [description](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html):

> Table 6-2. Source local host (our own machine)
>
> [...]
>
> 7. Routing decision, since the previous mangle and nat changes may have changed how the packet should be routed.
>
> [...]

there is a second route lookup after the OUTPUT chain, because NAT and other things might have changed the actual output interface. But in my tests I found that **it is impossible to change the output interface once it's chosen**.

For example, you have an application that sends an UDP packet from an unbound socket to some destination: the main table is queried and a default source, interface and gateway is chosen. Then you set a fwmark on it, and use that in policy-based routing to try put the packet on another interface:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 1
[root@localhost ~]# ip route add default dev lo table 1
```

The packet will have these lookups

```
#first lookup, assuming main NIC is in LAN with address 192.168.1.2/24, gateway 192.168.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
    cache 
#second lookup, source address and oif chosen
[root@localhost ~]# ip route get 8.8.8.8 oif eth0 from 192.168.1.2 mark 1
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  mark 1
    cache
```

Your packet will still have the already chosen output interface. Note that if you don't set the `oif` parameter you get the right interface:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.2 mark 1
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.2 dev lo  mark 1
    cache
```

So what's the point? It seems (and I have tested) that you can effectively only change the gateway, but you cannot even use `blackhole` or `unreachable`.